# PHP JSON and array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I've querying an API and I've got some troubles to display the code returned (JSON). If I do a var_dump, I have something like this:

```
var_dump($street['location']);

array(3) {
    ["latitude"]=> string(10) "52.6397278"
    ["street"]=> array(2) {
        ["id"]=> int(469)
        ["name"]=> string(23) "On or near Abbey Street"
    }
    ["longitude"]=> string(10) "-1.1322920"
}
```

Now, usually, I will do something like that to have it displayed:

```
var_dump($street['location']);
echo '->latitude:' . $location['latitude'] . '<br/>';
foreach($location['street'] as $st){
    echo '-->street id:' . $st['id'] . '<br/>';
    echo '-->street name:' . $st['name'] . '<br/>';
}
echo '->Longitude:' . $location['longitude'] . '<br/>';
```

But I get:

```
array(3) {
    ["latitude"]=> string(10) "52.6397278"
    ["street"]=> array(2) {
        ["id"]=> int(469)
        ["name"]=> string(23) "On or near Abbey Street"
    }
    ["longitude"]=> string(10) "-1.1322920"
} ->latitude:5

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/pasd529/public_html/npia.php on line 102
->Longitude:5
```

The latitude / longitude are truncated and I can't get the streed id / name ...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve the problem with the street:

```
$street['location'] = // array - it's not really clear in your code.   
echo '->latitude:' . $street['location']['latitude'] . '<br/>';
echo '-->street id:' . $street['location']['street']['id'] . '<br/>';
echo '-->street name:' . $street['location']['street']['name'] . '<br/>';
echo '->Longitude:' . $street['location']['longitude'] . '<br/>';
```

You do not need to iterate ofer the array to access the street information.

---

If you want to use `foreach` for the array stored in `$street['location']['street']`:

```
// ...
foreach($street['location']['street'] as $key => $value){
   echo '-->street ', $key, ': ', $value, '<br />';
}
// ...
```

(Note that you can don't need to concatenate using `.` when you just want to `echo` something and can just use the `,`.)

Comment: Thanks. Works fine. how do I know when I need to do a foreach or not ?

Comment: @Gianps Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to tell me.

Comment: @Olivier I've added an example to show you how `foreach` would work.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the help, much appreciate. @Gianps: yes, this might be code debugging, but sometimes people who are not developing all the day needs it ... And I REALLY APPRECIATE all the help I'm getting from here.

Comment: @Oliver: totally agree. was just pointing out that code isn't so clean and has to be used just for debug purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You're dumping out one value (`$street['location'])`, but are foreach looping on `$location['street']` instead. So most likely you've got your foreach value reversed.

If the var_dump is to be trusted, then you don't even need the foreach loop:

```
echo '->latitude:' . $location['latitude'] . '<br/>';
echo '-->street id:' . $location['street']['id'] . '<br/>';
echo '-->street name:' . $location['street']['name'] . '<br/>';
```